# Saving state of animation in android

Tags: android, animation

I have several images in my different layouts and I am Using `ZoomOut animation` on all of the images which are not in a respective layout.

```
The Issue Is:
```

The animation is called on `FocusChangeListener`, when i change the focus from one image to another in the same layout, the animation on all other images is called again. i want to save the state of zoomOut animation on all other images that are not in the relevant layout

```
My Question Is:
```

How can i save the state of animation so that whenever i change focus from one image to another in same layout the animation's state on all other images remain same, they remain in zoom out position.

I hope i have made my self clear?

```
    Code:

<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.8"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:toYScale="0.8" >
</scale>
```

Comment: post your code, let us see if we can fix it.

Comment: you should set animation in java class and save the state in variables